# how to monitor python wsgi server,when it crashed restart it

Tags: python, crash, wsgi, restart

i have a wsgi server which use paste,for some unkonw reason,it will often crash,so i want to has a application or just some package can help me to slove this,when it crashed automaticly kill the process and restart it.Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Investigating why the crash is occurring may be more beneficial. Otherwise I recommend .. a pid storage, page call check and restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use your operational system's service integration to do that. For example, on debian linux, there's start-stop-daemon. On windows, there's the service management.

It's the proven, well integrated way, provided by the operational system itself, to keep an application running.

Just make your installation program register your service with the native service management system.

Comment: my os is ubuntu server,could you give more detail information about how to use it,or some keywords i can gg

Comment: @mlzboy: ubuntu uses `start-stop-daemon` just like debian. For more information type `man start-stop-daemon`. You can check existing startup stripts at `/etc/init.d` for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to run your service. It provides auto-restart option in a program configuration.  You can reference to the autorestart section in this [document](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings).

To know how to use it with Python, you can reference to my answer on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572943/start-a-wsgi-app-from-within-virtualenv-as-a-linux-system-service/4632896#4632896).