# Start a wsgi app from within virtualenv as a Linux system service

Tags: python, linux, wsgi, bottle

I'm currently developing a bottle app within virtualenv. I intend to serve it using bjoern WSGI server (but that probably doesn't matter too much). I also intend to serve the app with a lighty or nginx reverse proxy. Anyhow, can the app be run from within its own virtualenv as a system service? And if so, how would one go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my experience, I suggest that you can use [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to run your web server as daemon service.  Although you can write some Linux service scripts in /etc/init.d, but they are really difficult to do it correctly.  Here is an [example init.d script for nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx-init-ubuntu) to run it as a service in Ubuntu.  You don't want to write one, do you?

To run a python server which depends on virtualenv as daemon service with supervisord, here is the configuration I am using in a production environment.

```
[program:web01]
command=/home/victorlin/tg2env/bin/paster serve production.ini ;
process_name=%(program_name)s ;
directory=/home/victorlin/ ;
user=victorlin ;
priority=999 ;
redirect_stderr=true ;
stdout_logfile=/home/victorlin/logs/web01_out.txt ;
stderr_logfile=/home/victorlin/logs/web01_err.txt ;
environment=PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/home/victorlin/.python-eggs ;
```

You can use /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python to run your own python script in the command field. And, to run the supervisord on start-up, you can write crontab like this in your root account:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/supervisord -c /home/root/supervisord.conf
```

Of course, if you don't have port numbers lower than 1024 to open, you can write this start-up crontab in a non-privilege account.

Comment: Rats! Supervisor not installable via easy_install... The download path listed on their own website seems obsolete.

Comment: Wouldn't install on the system. I don't know why. Anyway, I've solved it by writing my own init scripts. I'll keep your advice in mind in case supervisord decides to install in future. :) http://is.gd/ybPAb9